# Errors while launching wso2server.bat

Tags: wso2

I cloned the repository **https://github.com/wso2/product-emm** and I am trying to deploy the solution on a Windows 7 based environment but I got some problems !

When I run `maven install` on the projects it runs successfully and it generates a `wso2emm-1.1.8-SNAPSHOT.zip` under `%workDir%emm-wso2\modules\distribution\target`, I unzip it and I run wso2server.bat under `bin` directory but the command line shows some errors that stop me from running `localhost/:9443/dashboard.`

[Here is what the command line looks like](http://txt.do/5prz5)

Comment: Can you check if that you are getting same error for the actual released pack? That can be downloaded from the wso2 website

Comment: Well I am working with a team in a dev environment I do not have access to download or install newer versions ! The project we're working on is based on this specific version. I hope this will not complicate the situation more